# undefined method `should' for Date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to test behavior between 2 models

In `BudgetRule` model I have `after_create` method, which creates `Transaction` (another model).

I want to test `action_start` column in created transaction. In my tests it should be equal `Date.today`. So my `BudgetRule` test is the following:

```
require 'rspec'

describe BudgetRule do

  user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
  let(:budget_rule) { FactoryGirl.build(:budget_rule, user: user) }

  subject { budget_rule }

  it 'should add proper action start' do
    budget_rule.save!
    budget_transaction = Transaction.find_by(user: user, budget_rule: budget_rule)
    budget_transaction.action_start.should == Date.today
  end
end
```

But I receive

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `should' for Wed, 26 Feb 2014:Date
```

Thanks for any help!

UPDATE:

When I make:

```
budget_transaction.action_start should == Date.today #without dot before "should"
```

I receive

```
expected: Wed, 26 Feb 2014
     got: #<BudgetRule id: 7, ...and so on... "> (using ==)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after several fails, working tests are:

```
require 'rspec'

describe BudgetRule do

  user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
  budget_rule = FactoryGirl.create(:budget_rule, user: user)
  budget_transaction = Transaction.find_by(user: user, budget_rule: budget_rule)

  subject { budget_transaction }

  it 'should add proper action start' do
    expect(budget_transaction.action_start).to eq Date.today
  end

end
```

Hope it will help somebody some day :)